# C# localization doesn't work when opening the application by double clicking an associated file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, localization, resx

I deploy an application using WIX. It is a localized app and the user - obviously - can alternate between two languages. This works fine when the user opens the application directly. However this is not the case when the user opens the application by double clicking a file with an extension that I associated it with my application. I don't really understand the mechanism behind the localization i.e. where the language choice is saved. I would appreciate any guidance on how this should work when the user opens the application indirectly i.e. by double clicking another files that opens the application.

here how the culture initialization works

```
 protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {

        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(SurfaceApplication2.Properties.Settings.Default.Culture);
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
        if (e.Args != null && e.Args.Length > 0)
        {
            this.Properties["ArbitraryArgName"] = e.Args[0];
        }
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
```

and here how I alternate between the two languages.

```
private void SurfaceButton_Click_6(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.Culture.ToString().Equals("en-US"))
        {
            SurfaceApplication2.Properties.Settings.Default.Culture = "fr-FR";
            SurfaceApplication2.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            SurfaceApplication2.Properties.Settings.Default.Culture = "en-US";
            SurfaceApplication2.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Kind of hard to guide anyone without seeing existing code within the framework you are working with.. can you show the coded portion that pertains to your question.?

Comment: I don't know what code to share, WIX is just for the deployment and it is working fine. my questions is mainly on how the localization works and where the language chosen value is saved, then should I pass this when I double click the associated file ?

Comment: do you have an option to select the language or is this set on the server in the Culture settings..? how are you passing this are you using `queryString`..?

Comment: I just have a button that shows the other language , and when clicked it changes the Culture accordingly, but this is actually  working when opening the .exe application file. But opening the application using .abc file file which is associated with my app , the app opens but it always display the default English Culture

Comment: well then I would ask what controls that the first time and if you are reading from a file.. perhaps there is some caching going on.. it's really hard to give an answer when we can see what you see sorry

Comment: by default it is English , if the user chose to change it to French then it is French every time the user opens the application .exe, at  this time it returns to English when open by the double click on the associated file.

Comment: sounds like a problem in the coded end of the application can you debug that application